# How to extract coordinates of voxels/how to discretise a 3d object?

Tags: 3d, game-physics, voxel, x3d, vrml

I want to do some maths (translation, rotation, etc) with 3d objects which interact. At the moment, I have VRML, X3d, Maya and .jvxl versions of a 3d structure. I can visualize them just fine but I want to store these files as coordinates from a projection onto a 3d grid. I.e. I want to be able to store them in a manner similar to the way Minecraft world look, ie voxels. For example, if I had a .wrl file which represented a sphere, is there any program or way to project this sphere onto a grid of specified resolution, where I can assign each grid entry in which the sphere is present, a specific value?

Sorry if I'm unclear, I can clarify any questions

Comment: you need to be more specific about your inputs. the general appraoch of voxelisation is to check every grid position if it is inside or outside your shape (or if you have 3d data what kind of material is at the voxel position). a general approach does not exist (imagine open meshes: what's inside, what's outside? what to do with the open border?)

Comment: Yeah — do you want an actual solid, filled sphere or will a simple approach of filling any voxels that had geometry in them (so you'll get a hollow sphere) do? Due to the way many of them work, it might be worth looking into the 3d printing file formats and any conversion tools that map to them.

Comment: Well the problem is that at the moment I have software that can view the .wrl file I have, however I cannot really do anything apart from view it at the moment. I want to project the 3d object onto a grid. If it is only a surface, I would ideally like to include all the points on the interior. I'll have a look at that